# Array errors I'm facing using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm working on an assignment. Parallel arrays are required... I need help with a couple of things, well, at least three things.

- The first issue when I run the program all the way through. How do I
  add spaces in the print statement? It comes out like this
  "MondaySoda1.0"
- Another problem is the "1.0" I clearly have "1.25" for price [0] but
  why is it printing out "1.0"?
- Lastly, if I type in Tuesday where it asks "Which day of the week do
  you want...." It stills prints out the information for Monday. How do
  I code it where if you type in Tuesday, it does not print anything at
  all.

I'll appreciate any help at this point!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cafeteria  
{
public static void main (String [] args)
{

  String [] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday   ", "Saturday   ", "Sunday   "};   
  String [] drinks = {"Soda", "Sweet Tea", "Lemonade", "Frozen Lemonade", "Coffee-Hot", "Coffee-Iced", "Latte"}; 
  double [] price; = {1.25, 1.50, 1.75, 2.00, 2.25, 2.50, 3.75};

  for ( int i = 0; i < days.length; i++)
  {

  }  

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("What is the price of a Soda? ");
  price [0] = scan.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("What is the price of a Sweet Tea? ");
  price [1] = scan.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("What is the price of a Lemonade? ");
  price [2] = scan.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("What is the price of a Frozen Lemonade? ");
  price [3] = scan.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("What is the price of a Coffee-Hot? ");
  price [4] = scan.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("What is the price of a Coffee-Iced? ");
  price [5] = scan.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("What is the price of a Latte? ");
  price [6] = scan.nextDouble();
  System.out.println();

  scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Which day of the week do you want the discounted drink price for?");
  String day = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println();



  System.out.println("Weekday     Drink       Original-Price     Discount-Price");
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
  System.out.println(days[0] + drinks[0] + price[0]); //Print out the list of the desire array when you enter a day in


  System.out.println("The highest price drink is latte at $3.75");


 }
}
```

Comment: There isn't anything called *Parallel arrays* in java.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I just call them for this assignment's sake lol.

Comment: Nobody besides you understands that term. Maybe you rethink how funny it is to willingly confuse the people you are asking for help. In other words: please ask a clear question, and avoid anything that makes it *harder* to read than necessary.

Comment: Seriously... I am calling them arrays because my assignment have instruction to use "parallel" arrays. Stating word for word "(You will create 3 Parallel Arrays: Weekday, Drink & Price)."

Comment: I think in this particular case "parallel arrays" is a term your teacher uses to mean different arrays that are related through a common index. I.e. they all have the same size and for any i, array1[i] relates to array2[i]. I'm not sure if there is a common computer-science term for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here we go...

- > How do I add spaces in the print statement?

  Add spaces as shown below

  ```
  System.out.println(days[0] + "  " + drinks[0] + "  " + price[0]);
  ```
- > Another problem is the "1.0" I clearly have "1.25" for price [0] but
  >   why is it printing out "1.0"?

  Not sure what you mean, but if you input 1 it outputs 1.0 so on and so forth
- > Which day of the week do you want...." It stills prints out the
  >   information for Monday. How do I code it where if you type in Tuesday

  This is happening because you are storing the input in `day` and
  trying to use the index of array `days`. Just print out the `day`
  variable, you dont need the array `days`.

  ```
   System.out.println(day + "  " + drinks[0] + "  " + price[0]);
  ```

Comment: I see, so I would have to follow the same thing for drinks and price. That way if the user enter Tuesday, for example, it will print Tuesday, Lemonade, and the original price.

Comment: Well, how do I store the input in drinks?

Comment: Same way you did for price, but ideally you'll need to use a loop to store them rather than use the index each time.

Comment: Alright, I just redone my code all over again. Do you mind looking over it?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the right site for that I'm afraid. You can try [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site instead.

Comment: Thanks, I finally finished my assignment. Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have an extra semicolon after the *price* variable that should result in a compilation error:

```
double [] price; = {1.25, 1.50, 1.75, 2.00, 2.25, 2.50, 3.75};
```

Secondly you never use the values you instantiate the array with, you assign new values as you run the program. So if you answer the first question - "What is the price of a Soda?" - with *1*, then the end result will be *1.0*.

Thirdly, to add the required space, just add it when you print out the result:

```
System.out.println(days[0] + "  " + drinks[0] + "  " + price[0]);
```

Comment: My fault for putting price;

Answer (score 0):

Parallel arrays is not a thing, but you could of course make a new class, called e.g., Drink.

```
public class Drink {
    String drink;
    double price;

    public Drink(String drink) {
        this.drink = drink;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDrink() {
        return drink;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

This way, you can use the constructor to create the drink and the setter to set the price, after you got the user input. You could also include a field for discount (or discount of the day) or something.

In your scenario, not sure where the days are for...

Comment: I have made a class to store your Drinks. Pretty much the basics of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming